# Как сбросить маршрут?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

```
    function (){
     // Задаём точки мультимаршрута.
        var pointA = [координаты а],
            pointB = [координаты б],

            multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
                referencePoints: [
                    pointA,
                    pointB
                ],
                params: {
                    //Тип маршрутизации - пешеходная маршрутизация.
                    routingMode: 'pedestrian'
                }
            }, {
                // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
                boundsAutoApply: true
            });

        // Добавляем мультимаршрут на карту.
        myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
    }
```

Не выходит сбросить маршрут при изменений маршрута или координат, только по перезагрузке.
Работает это так
На балуне есть кнопка построить маршрут.
Из местонахождения пользователя до балуна строится маршрут, но если я просматриваю другой балун и строю маршрут то он добавляется к предыдущему.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к балунам сброс маршрута перед построением нового:

```
myMap.geoObjects.remove(multiRoute);
```